# Regex pattern to replace html in a given text string

Tags: regex, apex-code

I am trying to extract the text from the below html snippet. Need help in regex pattern that will replace all the html tag and only will leave out the content.

I tried to remove the `<span*>` using the below expression but that didn't do the trick.

```
 String x = '<span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="line-height:107%;"><span style="font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;"><strong><font color="#000000">Some normal text here...</font></strong></span></span></span>';
 String y = x.replaceAll('[<span*\b>]','');
 system.debug(y);
```

This prints out:

```
  tyle="fot-ize:11t;" tyle="lie-height:107%;" tyle="fot-fmily:Clibri, -erif;"trogfot color="#000000"Some normal text here.../fot/trog///
```

So it basically replaced the each character individually and not the content between the `<span ... >`

Need Help

Comment: `.replaceAll("<span.*?>","")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line of code should be:

```
String y = x.replaceAll('<span[^>]*>','');
```

The meaning of this statement is: for all the occurrences of `'<span'` followed by many occurences (`*`) of anything but `'>'` (`[^>]`) followed by a single `'>'`, replace by nothing.

By the way, you will miss the closing tab `</span>`. I tell this just for your information, because you didn't ask for this.